# C++, include или forward-declaration в заголовках

Tags: c++, include

Существует два противоположных мнения, относительно включения одних заголовков в другие.

1. Подключение заголовков внутри заголовков - это очень плохо. Всегда, когда возможно, должна использоваться предварительная декларация. Это положительно сказывается на времени компиляции. К тому же, в заголовок будет попадать меньше мусора.
2. Если заголовку нужны другие заголовки, то их следует включать, а предварительное объявление использовать только в самых крайних случаях. Например, для разрыва циклической зависимости заголовков.

Как же поступать правильно?

Идея использования предварительных объявлений казалась мне удачной, пока я не начал сталкиваться с шаблонными типами, а так же с вещами, которые определены через `typedef`. К примеру, я так и не смог придумать, как сделать предварительное объявление для `std::string` вместо включения `<string>`.

Comment: include заголовка, содержащего forward declaration. Непонятно, почему это они противоположные, это стандартная практика. Стандартная библиотека не предоставляет такого заголовка, соответственно никаких forward declaration для типов из стандартной библиотеки быть не должно.

Comment: @VTT, например, если мне в хедере не нужны полные типы, я могу использовать `#include`, а могу `forward-declaration`. Первое увеличивает время компиляции и иногда приводит к циклическим зависимостям. Второе - не всегда тривиально реализовать для шаблонов и `typedef` штук.

Comment: Когда необходимо forward-declaration, то следует сделать include заголовочного файла, содержащего эти forward-declaration (обычно такие заголовочные файлы называются `_fwd.hpp`  или `.forward.hpp` [пример](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Tagged-Tuple/blob/master/include/vtt/container/Tagged%20Tuple.forward.hpp)), а не плодить новые в текущем файле.

Comment: @VTT, мне кажется, мы друг друга как-то не так понимаем.

Comment: ни разу не слышал ни одного из правил.

Comment: Как Вы правильно заметили, есть 2 мнения. А раз они есть до сих пор, значит никакого «правильного» мнения не существует, есть только выбор, который остаётся за каждым программистом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИМХО, первый вариант (копирование предварительных объявлений и прототипов в несколько .cpp файлов) слишком сильно портит качество кода.

Если так нужна скорость компиляции, то если другие (менее радикальные, и более действенные) способы ее поднять:

- Предкомпилированные заголовки.
- Более быстрый компилятор, например Clang вместо GCC.
- Более быстрый линковщик, например LLD вместо LD.